# Footer gallery is vertical instead of grid

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I am battling an issue on one page of my wordpress site. Through the cornerstone editor, my footer looks fine on all pages, but when doing an outside venture to my site, I saw that ONLY on my quote page the gallery overflowed outside the container and was vertical instead of a grid.

The gallery is a plugin called envira gallery.

So far I added "overflow: hidden" to a new class I called envira-gall. I tried "position: absolute;" and "position: relative;", but they were no help.

I would add a snippet of code, but I really don't know where to start to tackle this issue and I'm still a little new to html and css...

I am trying to figure out what is forcing the gallery to become vertical on my quote page. www.barnhart-trans.com/test

[What my image is doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eguUq.png)

[What it should be doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yoN1.png)

Comment: Please show us something.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and dont forget to add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)a

Answer (score 0):

Alright thank you to the web dev group on facebook I have solved the issue! I created a new page in x-theme, saved my current page as a template, copied the saved template to the new page, and then loaded it in a private browser. The gallery displayed correctly! Next I added my custom css for my contact form 7. The gallery was distorted again. So I did a lot of trial and error commenting code out to figure out I left a "}" out at the end of my custom css.